# Do I need hook_update_N if there are no database changes?

Tags: updating

I wrote a little module that provides a form and does some special processing of the submission.  There are no database tables involved. If I change the form or processing, how do I code the update? Do I still use hook_update_N if the module update doesn't affect the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If the changes are just code, (not db schema changes, content changes, variable changes, data changes in general), then you don't need an update hook, no.

Basic rule of thumb: will your code updates break anything for existing or new users? If not, you don't need an update hook.